# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread from docker containers

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose

We have some `java` and `c++` processes running in a docker container with `IBM MQ` and `DB2`.

Everything works fine when 1 container is running, but we get

`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread when we run more than 4 containers.`

Things we tried :

> 1) set ulimit using docker-compose file.
>
> 2) set ulimit in bashrc of  user which is running the processes inside
>   the container.

With this changes, we faced `"fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable"` error on host VM.

We reverted those changes and tried setting ulimit of user who is running docker-compose command  :

> 1) set in .bashrc
>
> 2) set using root

We are still observing the `OOM : native thread error.`

Comment: IBM DB2 and MQ are robust products. How large is each image and how many of each of those enterprise server processes are you running? And how much memory does the physical host have?

Comment: 3 images in 1 set - 1) image size = 846 MB. 2) 199 MB. 3) 5 MB. We are running 4 sets . Host VM memory - 429 GB.

Comment: That doesn't sound right. Relational databases use a lot of ram.

Comment: docker system df command output - 
images = 19 (active-3) (size = 72 GB) 
containers = 3 (active-3) (size = 2.8 GB)
volumes = 303 (active-0) (size = 3.6 GB)